# How to get the specific multiple value out from a list in python and If the user input is equal to the mulitple values print output

Tags: python

```
Pass=[0,20,40,60,80,100,120]
while True:
    Pass_Input=int(input("Enter : "))
    if Pass_Input in Pass[5:6]:
        print("Progress")
    elif Pass_Input in Pass[0:2]:
        print("Progress Module Trailer")
    elif Pass_Input in Pass[0]:
        print("Exclude")
```

Input:

```
Enter : 120
```

Output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\IIT\Python\CW_Python\1 st question 2nd try.py", line 8, in <module>
    elif Pass_Input in Pass[0]:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Output I expect:

```
Progress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass[5:6] is [100]
and 120 is not in [100] with no doubt.

list slice Pass[5:6] means from 5 to 6, which 5 is included and 6 is not.

```
In [1]: Pass=[0,20,40,60,80,100,120]
In [2]: Pass[5:6]
Out[2]: [100]
```

then the program runs to `elif Pass_Input in Pass[0]:` . Pass[0] is 0, which can not be iterable, so you get a TypeError

---

you can change Pass[5:6] to Pass[5:7] to get `Process` output

Answer (score 0):

In your last elif evaluation, you are using **Pass[0]** which is not a list but a value. You should write

```
elif Pass_Input == Pass[0]
```